# Google Wallet returning "unsupported user agent" error on iOS7, previously worked

Tags: ios7, android-pay

Today we noticed that our “Google wallet” button is not loading in iOS 7 devices. After debugging we are getting an error “unsupported user agent“ from “google.wallet.online.createWalletButton” ready callback function.     The code snippet is,

```
            google.wallet.online.createWalletButton({
                                            "jwt" : jwt,
                                            "success" : createWalletSuccess,
                                            "failure" : createWalletFailure,
                                             "ready" : createWalletReady
            });
```

In createWalletReady callback, we are getting the following message from wallet:

{"status":"FAILURE","error":"UNSUPPORTED_USER_AGENT","details":"Safari is not supported with http:// use https:// to support Safari"}

But in IOS lower versions (6.x & 5.x) it is loading successfully.

I have searched Google's docs and the web in general for information, but so far have been out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this is to make *all* Google Wallet Instant Buy calls from secure pages.

So in your example, the page where "Buy With Google" button is rendered (where you have the snippet) should also be a https page.

EDIT: 
And the documentation is also updated. refer to https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/web/tutorial#call_authorize_to_determine_checkout_page_behavior  (see Important note).

Comment: although https in not a possibility in our circumstance, this is truly the correct answer for most that will run into issues with google wallet over http.  Accepting this answer.